# setting state covariance matrix in statsmodel.tsa.UnobservedComponents

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to impose smoothness on the state covariance matrix, while using frequency domain seasonal components. I initiate my model as follows with a local level component and a particular frequency and harmonics specified.

```
model = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(df, level='llevel',
                                    freq_seasonal=[{'period':130.51, 'harmonics':2}],
                                    stochastic_freq_seasonal=[True])
res = model.fit()
>>>
sigma2.irregular                  0.730561
sigma2.level                      0.187833
sigma2.freq_seasonal_130.51(2)    0.003718
```

This will generate some parameter values as noted above. Now Since I am using 2 harmonics there are in fact 4 error variance and I want to set them as follows

```
model.ssm.state_cov[1,1,0] = 17.65
model.ssm.state_cov[2,2,0] = 0.3102
model.ssm.state_cov[3,3,0] = 17.65
model.ssm.state_cov[4,4,0] = 0.3102
```

And then get a 'smooth' and 'filter' object and see how they do. I know i can set the parameters under `res.params`, but these 4 do no appear in the parameter list. Is there a way to do it in this library?

Comment: linking master Chad here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603962/cfulton) cfulton

Answer (score 1):

The implementation in Statsmodels assumes a single common error variance parameter across all of the seasonal harmonic error terms, as in Harvey (1989, "Forecasting, Structural Time Series, and the Kalman Filter") section 2.3.4.

As a result, it's not particularly easy to set those parameters as you have suggested and then estimate the remaining parameters.

However, it is possible. For this specific case, you can set the variance parameters to 1 and then put the square root of the variance terms you actually want into the diagonals of the selection matrix, as follows:

```
model = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(df, level='llevel',
                                    freq_seasonal=[{'period':130.51, 'harmonics':2}],
                                    stochastic_freq_seasonal=[True])

model['selection', 1:, 1:] = np.diag([17.65, 0.3102, 17.65, 0.3102])**0.5
with model.fix_params({'sigma2.freq_seasonal_130.51(2)': 1}):
    res = model.fit()
```

Comment: Thanks @cfulton. That did the job. Is there a mechanism to do additive models in this framework like in https://pydlm.github.io/, e.g. were i can have separate model class for trend, seasonality, AR components and add them to learn and infer from?